# How do I prevent cache in jsp and sightly html in the first instance

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I am facing issue to reflect changes immediately in AEM after I make some changes in jsp /sightly.

How do I prevent cache in jsp and sightly html in the first instance. I am using AEM6 SP2.

Comment: Are you referring caching at the AEM or dispatcher? Can you explain your scenario?

Comment: I am referring to AEM only. Not dispatcher.

Comment: @Thomas, I am using ACS commons error page handler and when I test it by throwing an error in a design dialog, I do get redirected to a 500 page, however, when I revert back the cause of error, the error page keep on showing up. This happens only with design_dialog. With dialog it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `Dispatcher: no-cache` header to any pages that you want to prevent from being cached. In JSP:

```
<%
  response.setHeader("Dispatcher", "no-cache");
%>
```

If you'd like to set this header from a Sightly script, simply include a small JSP (`no-cache.jsp`, for example) that sets the above header: `<sly data-sly-include="no-cache.jsp" />`.

Edit: for more information on caching with the Dispatcher check out this deck: http://www.slideshare.net/andrewmkhoury/aem-cq-dispatcher-caching-webinar-2013

Answer (score 0):

Is this an issue related with Sling caching anyhow:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-4256  ?